# Hide/unhide slides not work fine if I go to the end of the show

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a powerpoint with a macro.

1) at the begin, **the last 4 slides** of the show **are hidden**.

2) When I run my show, I go on **a slide which contains 4 checkboxes**. **These checkboxes can hide or unhide the last 4 slides. If I check, then, the slide is unhidden and if I uncheck, in the same way, the slide is hidden**. For example, I check the checkbox number 3 and only the slide number 3 is unhidden. Or, I check the checkboxes number 2 and 4 and only the slides number 2 and 4 are unhidden. On the contrary, if I uncheck the checkbox, for example number 2, I hide the slide number 2.

[image: the slide with 4 checkboxes which hide/unhide the last 4 slides]

3) for the example, **I check the checkboxes number 1 and 3** which **unhide the slides number 1 and 3**.

[image: I check the checkboxes number 1 and 3]

4) When **I go to the next slide** after this, **only the slides number 1 and 3 are unhidden**. Good.

5) Then, **I go back to the slide containing the checkboxes**.

6) I **uncheck the checkboxes number 1 and 3** and **check the number 4**.

[image: I unchecked the checkboxes number 1 and 3 and, then, check the number 4]

7) **I go to the next slide** and **only the slide number 4 is unhidden**. Good.

8) Now, **I go to the next slide from where I'm at, the slide number 4**, and there is no more slide. So, **I see the end's screen of the show**.

[image: The end's screen]

**9) If I decide to go back to the show from this end, I see the slide number 4, but also, the slides number 1 and 3 that I unchecked before at the 6). My trouble is that I don't understand why the slides that I unchecked which would be hidden, are unhidden if I go back from the end's screen of the show ?**

I try to find an explanation on the Web but I didn't find something on this trouble.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: if you provide some code and a screenshot you will be more likely to get the help you need.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can repro something like this this w/o using code in PPT 2016.

If this will run on a PC that you control, do this:

File | Options | Advanced
Under "Slide Show", remove the check next to "End with black slide"
Click OK

Now PPT will simply end the show when the user is on the last slide and tries to go forward.

Comment: Thanks for the help !